# Docbook 4 Insert programming language code

Tags: docbook, docbook-5

Does anyone know how insert a programming code in DOCBOOK 4 format?
I use Oxygen Xml Editor. I try < code > but it does not work well
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `programlisting` element for multiline blocks or `code` for inline code. Further details can be found at http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/ProgramListings.html.